# Error in my C++ code using linked-list

Tags: c++, data-structures

i have a problem when i run my code in case 1 and 3, case 1 and case 3 doesn't do what i want..
if you enter "1" you should enter a new customer and if you enter "3" the program will display the list. the program doesn't do this, where's the problem ?

here's the Header.h "header file"

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class customer
{
public:
    string name;
    int gsize;
    int status;
    customer* next;

    customer();
    customer(string,int,int);

};

class waitinglist
{
public:
    int tables; //number of occupied tables
    int chairnum;
    int totalcustomers;
    customer*head,*tail;
    waitinglist();
    waitinglist(int);
    void newcustomer(string,int,int);
    void diplaycustomer(string);
    void displayall();
};
```

and this is the Source.cpp with main

```
            #include"Header.h"

customer::customer()
{
    name="";
    gsize=status=0;
    next=NULL;
}

customer::customer(string name1,int gsize1,int status1)
{
    name=name1;
    gsize=gsize1;
    status=status1;
    next=NULL;
}

waitinglist::waitinglist()
{
    chairnum=totalcustomers=tables=0;
    head=tail=NULL;
}
waitinglist::waitinglist(int val)
{
    chairnum=val;
    totalcustomers=0;
    tables=0;
    head=tail=NULL;
}

void waitinglist::newcustomer(string name1,int gsize1 ,int status1)
{
    customer*tmp= new customer;
    if (head==NULL)            // linkedlist is empty
    {
        head = tail = tmp;
        totalcustomers++;
    }
    else
    {
        tmp->next = head;
        head = tmp;
        totalcustomers++;
    }

}

void waitinglist::displayall()
{
    customer *tmp;
    tmp = head;
    while(tmp != NULL)
    {
        cout<<tmp->name <<" "<<tmp->gsize<<"-->"; 
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void waitinglist::diplaycustomer(string Name)
{
    customer*tmp ;
    tmp=head ;
    cin>>Name ;
    while(tmp!=NULL )
    {
        if (Name==tmp->name)
        {
        cout << "the name : "<< tmp->name << endl ;
        cout << "the group size = "<<tmp->gsize << endl ;
        cout << "the status : " << tmp->status <<endl;
          break ;
        }
        else if (Name!=tmp->name)
        {
        tmp=tmp->next;
        }
    }
    if (tmp==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"can't found! ";
    }

}

int main()
{
    int choice;
    string namevar=" ";
    int gsizevar=0;
    int statusvar=0;
    waitinglist mylist;
    do
    {
        cout<<"Note: 1 in status means{the customer not here and 2 means the customer is here.}\n";
        cout<<"Select your option.\n\n";
        cout<<"(1) Add a new Customer.\n";
        cout<<"(2) Display information based on Name.\n";
        cout<<"(3) List all Names.\n";
        cout<<"(4) Quit.\n\n";
        cout<<"Enter your choice: -->  ";

        cin>>choice;

        if (1 <= choice && choice <= 3)
        {   
            switch (choice)
            {
            case 1:
                mylist.newcustomer(namevar,gsizevar,statusvar);
                break;
            case 2:
                mylist.diplaycustomer(namevar);
                break;
            case 3:
                mylist.displayall();
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Invalid choice.  Enter again.\n\n";
                break;
            }
        }   
    }
    while (choice != 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please paste the error too

Comment: the error is the code doesn't do what i want!
i don't know why ?

Comment: @drescherjm i explained at the beginning..  the program doesn't do what i want, when you enter num 1 you should add new customer but the program doesn't do that

Comment: @Sreekar i explained at the beginning.. the program doesn't do what i want, when you enter num 1 you should add new customer but the program doesn't do that

Comment: Why are you asking for the name in diplaycustomer()? That is certainly not the place to ask for the name. You should have asked for the name before you call newcustomer. And pass newcustomer the name.

Comment: @drescherjm i'm asking for name to display his information.. the problem in the case number 1 and 3

Comment: You did not put the name of any customer in the list so it will not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user enters `1` as the choice, you call:

```
mylist.newcustomer(namevar,gsizevar,statusvar);
```

However, you don't have any code to gather `namevar`, `gsizevar`, and `statusvar` from the user. You just use the value with which they were initialized:

```
string namevar=" ";
int gsizevar=0;
int statusvar=0;
```

The function `newcustomer` adds a new customer to using those values.

You need to add code to gather those data from the user, either before you call `newcustomer`, or inside `newcustomer` before you use those values.

If you decide to gather the data from the user inside `newcustomer`, there is no need to pass them as variables.

Suggestion for cleanup:

You are asking the user to enter the name in `diplaycustomer`. Hence, there is no need to pass `namevar`. You can just use:

```
void waitinglist::diplaycustomer()
{
   customer*tmp ;
   tmp=head ;

   // Use a local variable.
   string Name;
   cin>>Name ;

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why the program doesn't do what you want it to do. For instance you don't use the name provided when constructing a new customer (and that name is surely empty anyway).
You should use a debugger and put breakpoints to understand what's happening in your code.